# How to handle on back pressed method

Tags: java, android

I have source for play station 1 games.
I want when user click to start button and go to play activity.
user can click on back pressed or show a button to go previos activity.
my onbackpressed method not dont work.and there is no view to add button.
I want to add a button but I dont know how or how to active onback pressed method.

here is my start activity method:

```
      public static void startRetroActivity(Intent retro, String contentPath, String corePath,
                                      String configFilePath, String imePath, String dataDirPath) {
    if (contentPath != null) {
        retro.putExtra("ROM", "/storage/emulated/0/" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/images/data.bin");
    }
    retro.putExtra("LIBRETRO", corePath);
    retro.putExtra("CONFIGFILE", configFilePath);
    retro.putExtra("IME", imePath);
    retro.putExtra("DATADIR", dataDirPath);
}
```

and here I use this method:

```
  Intent retro;
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "111", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        retro = new Intent(getActivity(), RetroActivityFuture.class);
    } else {
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "222", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        retro = new Intent(getActivity(), RetroActivityPast.class);

    }

    UserPreferences.updateConfigFile(getActivity());
    MainMenuFragment.startRetroActivity(
            retro,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + (new StringBuilder(ikol)).reverse().toString(),
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/cores/pcsx_rearmed_libretro_neon_android.so",
            UserPreferences.getDefaultConfigPath(getActivity()),
            Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD),
            getActivity().getApplicationInfo().dataDir);
    startActivity(retro);
```

and there is my activity:

```
 public final class RetroActivityFuture extends RetroActivityCamera {
private Intent exitIntent;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    //stopService(exitIntent);
    super.onPause();

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //exitIntent = new Intent(this , AdService.class);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //stopService(exitIntent);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    //stopService(exitIntent);
    //startService(exitIntent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //stopService(exitIntent);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

my RetroActivityCommon :

```
  public class RetroActivityCommon extends RetroActivityLocation
    {
@Override
public void onLowMemory()
{
}

@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level)
{
}


public void onRetroArchExit()
{
    System.exit(0);
}
  }
```

and here is my RetroActivityLocation :

```
     public class RetroActivityLocation extends NativeActivity
implements LocationListener

  {

private static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 0;

private Location mCurrentLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = null;
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
boolean locationChanged = false;
boolean location_service_running = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}


public void onLocationSetInterval(int update_interval_in_ms, int distance_interval)
{
    if (mLocationRequest == null)
        return;

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (update_interval_in_ms == 0)
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5 * 1000);
    else
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(update_interval_in_ms);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
}

public void onLocationInit()
{


    mUpdatesRequested = false;

    if (mLocationRequest == null)
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    onLocationSetInterval(0, 0);
}

public void onLocationStart()
{


    mUpdatesRequested = true;

}

public void onLocationFree()
{

}
public void onLocationStop()
{

}

public double onLocationGetLatitude()
{
    return mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
}

public double onLocationGetLongitude()
{
    return mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
}


public double onLocationGetHorizontalAccuracy()
{
    return mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy();
}
public boolean onLocationHasChanged()
{
    boolean hasChanged = locationChanged;
    if (hasChanged)
        locationChanged = false;

    return hasChanged;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if (!location_service_running)
        return;

    locationChanged = true;
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    String msg = "Updated Location: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude();
    Log.i("RetroArch GPS", msg);
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    onLocationStop();
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

look in acivity I have nothing.and RetroActivityCamera  extend native activity.
any suggestion?

Comment: why there is no view to add any button? You have to inflate view in onCreate method

Comment: If i add any view to my activity , my screen became black totally.

Comment: I got your question but need to ask some questions to confirm it 1) Please tell me activity name which has view and extended by your activity ?

Comment: you suppose to call Super.setContentView(back pressed view ) , then need to ovverride setContentView() method and you can add your back button over there and you can handle that from your child activity

Comment: non of my activity has view and would you please give simple code for more clarification

Comment: without view not able to add button OR handle its ClickListeners!!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `finish()` in `onBackPressed` method.

Comment: then add button and call `finish()` when user clicks it.

Comment: where? Have you read my question completely? I said that onBackPressed do not work

Comment: In your activity's layout add:
`<Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`
in your activity's onCreate method:
`Button exitButton;


        exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });`